Create "Pass/Fail/Caution" status in pandas dataframe based another columns without "SettingWithCopy" warning
I wrote code where:

All values above 3 are marked as "Fail".
Values between 1 and 3 marked as "Caution".

However I have the following warning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. And I'm not sure how I could avoid this warning.
Current code:
import pandas as pd
values = range(6)
df = pd.DataFrame({"Values":values, "Caution limit": [1]*len(values), "Fail limit": [3]*len(values)})
df["Status"] = "Pass"
df["Status"][df["Caution limit"] < df["Values"]] = "Caution"
df["Status"][df["Fail limit"] < df["Values"]] = "Fail"

Current Output:



Values
Caution limit
Fail limit
Status




0
1
3
Pass


1
1
3
Pass


2
1
3
Caution


3
1
3
Caution


4
1
3
Fail


5
1
3
Fail



Warning message:
C:\.....py:5: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  df["Status"][df["Caution limit"] < df["Values"]] = "Caution"
C:\.....py:6: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  df["Status"][df["Fail limit"] < df["Values"]] = "Fail"

UPD:
I found a way avoiding the SettingWithCopyWarning using lambda function:
update_status = lambda value, caution, failed: ["Fail" if f<v else "Caution" if c<v else "Pass" for v,c,f in zip(value, caution, failed)]
df["Status"] = update_status(df["Values"],df["Caution limit"],df["Fail limit"])

However it completely avoids using pandas capability and my main goal is to learn how I could use pandas to do so.

You're modifying a slice of the original dataframe, and not a copy of the data, which may be unclear in some situations. It's not an error in the Pandas version you're using, so you just get a warning. If you don't upgrade Pandas, you shouldn't have a problem with your current code.
In more recent versions of Pandas 2, there is a new warning referring to a future change in Pandas 3, when the code you're using will actually be modifying a copy of the original data -- and your code will not work anymore. Read more here.
To avoid the warning and possible future errors, you can modify the dataframe in place with loc:
df.loc[df["Caution limit"] < df["Values"], "Status"] = "Caution"
df.loc[df["Fail limit"] < df["Values"], "Status"] = "Fail"

Or using mask as an alternative:
df["Status"] = df["Status"].mask(df["Caution limit"] < df["Values"], "Caution")
df["Status"] = df["Status"].mask(df["Fail limit"] < df["Values"], "Fail")

Both will output the following with no warnings:
   Values  Caution limit  Fail limit   Status
0       0              1           3     Pass
1       1              1           3     Pass
2       2              1           3  Caution
3       3              1           3  Caution
4       4              1           3     Fail
5       5              1           3     Fail


Thank you for your answer I haven't heard about "mask" before.

you can use np.select to avoid the warning:
m = (df["Values"] > 1) & (df["Values"] <= 3)
n =  df["Values"] > 3

condList = [m, n]
choiceList = ['Caution', 'Fail']

df['Status'] = np.select(condList, choiceList, 'Pass')


Output:
  Values  Caution limit  Fail limit   Status
0       0              1           3     Pass
1       1              1           3     Pass
2       2              1           3  Caution
3       3              1           3  Caution
4       4              1           3     Fail
5       5              1           3     Fail


Thank you for your answer, it is very nice alternative way of doing it using numpy!

Code
Use pd.cut if the criteria applied is the same in all rows (1 and 3 are the criteria in all rows)
df['Status'] = pd.cut(
    df['Values'], 
    bins=[float('-inf'), 1, 3, float('inf')], 
    labels=['Pass', 'Caution', 'Fail']
)


Use np.select if the values in the Caution limit column and the Fail limit column are different for each row, so that the criteria is different for each row
import numpy as np
cond1 = df['Values'] <= df['Caution limit']
cond2 = df['Values'] <= df['Fail limit']
df['Status'] = np.select([cond1, cond2], ['Pass', 'Caution'], 'Fail')

